# The logic for re.match() , sys.exit(1) does not make sense, plus why can't i use return True if the re.match regex matches

Tags: python

The whole idea behind this ,is the user enters :
1. hg commit -m "NO-TIK" and is able to submit the changeset
2. hg commit -m "NO-REVIEW" also does the same as # 1
3. hg commit -m "JIRA-123 blah blah" is also submitted as long as there is a valid issue "JIRA-123" otherwise the commit is reverted with the message "%s does not exist"%ticket
4. hg commit -m "plain english without ANY of the above, reverts the changes , so the above 3 rules MUST be observed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re, os, sys, jira, subprocess
from optparse import OptionParser
import warnings
from collections import namedtuple


def verify_commit_text(tags):
    for line in tags:
        if re.match(r'[^\NO-TIK]',line):
            sys.exit(1)
        elif re.match(r'[^\NO-REVIEW]', line):
            sys.exit(1)
        elif re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]+-\d+', line):
            # Validate the JIRA ID
            m = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+-\d+)",line)
            m_args = m.group(1)
            m_args = [m_args]
            if CheckForJiraIssueRecord(m_args):
                sys.exit(1)
            else:
                print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args)
        else:
            sys.exit(0)

def CheckForJiraIssueRecord(my_args):
    # turn off stdout
    #sys.stdout = open(os.devnull)
    #sys.stderr = open(os.devnull)
    com = jira.Commands()
    logger = jira.setupLogging()
    jira_env = {'home':os.environ['HOME']}
    command_name = "cat"
    server = "http://jira.server.com:8080/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl"
    options = namedtuple('Options', 'user password')('user','password')
    jira.soap = jira.Client(server)
    jira.start_login(options, jira_env, command_name, com, logger)
    issue = com.run(command_name, logger, jira_env, my_args)
    if issue:
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commit_text_verified = verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"'))
    if commit_text_verified:
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, ('[obey the rules!]')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: i know using sys.exit(1) is reverse of what should be used, but that is the only way , this works

Comment: Does this code work? Or you asking for help fixing something?

Comment: this code works, but i had to reverse the logic to make it work, like 
 if re.match(r'[^\NO-TIK]',line):
            sys.exit(1)
but in Python sys.exit(0) is success, etc
and the function CheckForJiraIssueRecord 
returning True if issue, not sure of this is correct way, just wanted some one who has python experience to comment on my code, even though i know it sucks, but at least i would learn, how else would i know? right?

Comment: This code does not, in any sense, work.  `verify_commit_text` simply stops running with weird OS status codes all over the place.  This is not a good code review question.  This is a better StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem confused about `sys.exit` is doing. It exits your program. You function verify_commit_text never exits. Your code after calling verify_commit_text is never executed. The program always hits a sys.exit in verify_commit_text and terminates. The first thing you need to do is eliminate all the sys.exit() except in the `__main__` section. You should really only have sys.exit in there.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it, one more question:
What is the best way to call CheckForJiraIssueRecord(my_args):
from within verify_commit_text(tags):
since that is the code that makes a soap call and seturns a WSDL, and then verifies if "my_args" which seem to be a list is indeed a valid ticket number or not: These are the sample tags that get returned:
Key: JIRA-65
Summary: Summary of the issue (the most recent versions) are installed on the server
Reporter: reporter
Assignee: user
Description: None
Environment: None
Project: ABC
Votes: 0
Type: Task
Status: Open

Comment: @kamal, the best way to call that function is to call that function... I'm not sure what exactly your concern there is. If you remove all the sys.exit() and posted the new version of your code as an edit on your question, I'll review it again for anything that can be improved. Sys.exit is just such a big thing that it needs to be fixed before I can point out any small things.